# Prototype for 8x8 RGB LED display

Tags: led, video, rgb

I am planning to build a small, very low-resolution, 8x8 RGB LED display, which would be able to display a video (some kind of colorful visualization, lo-res) or a picture from PC via DVI or HDMI cable and USB. I chose this size because I want it to be more like a prototype, which, if successful, would become a much much bigger display, but that's for the future..

I have around 100 common cathode RGB LEDs lying around, so I would like to use them instead of buying an already made RGB LED matrix.

End goal will be to build a much bigger screen (RGB LED wall), composed of many smaller RGB LED modules, which will be able to display high resolution videos and images from PC.

Now, I am looking for information concerning:

1. Full overview of similar systems and schematics.
2. What separate components are needed to make such system work? Meaning, do I need to use RGB LED drivers and if so, what kind? What about DVI/HDMI video decoders? I do know that I will need a microprocessor to run and control all the other parts, but then again, I am not sure which to choose? PIC, ATmega, Raspberry Pi or even an Arduino board?
3. Similar projects and documentation. If You did or do know that someone else did such project successfully, please post links with helpful info so I could research them!

Comment: How experienced are you with electronics?  From your question, it seems like you aren't sure where to look for this information which is found in Arduino forums all over the place as well as other hobbyist/beginner areas.

Comment: DVI, HDMI and USB are three different things with different protocols & standards, getting video out of one of them could be a very different job to getting video out of another. Happily all three are documented in tedious detail, and if reading the documentation isn't enough to put you off then good luck to you.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to make one of these: [MeggyJr](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2008/meggy-jr-rgb/), except that MeggyJr doesn't take external signals at all. I've made one myself using ATmega328, but instead of using their more complex LED Matrix driver IC, I modified it to use a few 74HC595 and ULN2003 darlington arrays. Look for LED matrix on Google for more info. But I agree with @Funkyguy that this is a pretty complex project to start with.

Comment: To understand what type of questions to ask, what not to ask, and and how to ask, look at the [Help Centre](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 4):

This might be a case of "you don't know what you don't know."

Have you driven RGB LEDs with a microcontroller before? Have you connected a single color LED to a small microcontroller and made it blink (the equivalent of "Hello World" in EE)? You have to start somewhere, and I would highly recommend doing some basics before adding the complexity of an LED matrix and video decoding.

So, to address your points:

1. This site does not provide full schematics. It is meant to ask specific questions and get specific answers. You'll have to find or design a schematic on your own. You are welcome to post questions *about* a schematic, asking for help with specific parts or request critiques.
2. At its most fundamental, a block diagram of your intended project will include a video input/decoder, a microcontroller, and output. Deciding what components go into each of these blocks is not a simple thing. There are questions that need to be addressed, like

   - What resolution should the input video be? Will the device handle multiple resolutions? What frame rate and format?
   - How fast should the output refresh? Is its frame rate the same as the input video? Can it be slower?
   - Will the LEDs be directly driven, or multiplexed? What amount of flicker is acceptable? How bright do they need to be? Is color accuracy important?

   Until these (and many other) questions are addressed, it's not possible to suggest a particular microcontroller or other components.
3. There are numerous RGB LED "cubes" and display projects to be found across the internet at sites like [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/index) and [Make](http://makezine.com/projects/). There are products to help give you a jump start, like this [8x8 RGB matrix at Robot Shop](http://www.robotshop.com/en/8x8-led-rgb-matrix.html). You might want to check some of those out, and come back with more specific questions as you go.